# Wagtail Form Builder: Make the Custom Form Submission a Foreign Key in Another Model and Auto Update it on Submit

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm creating an app in wagtail using the form builder. I've added a custom form submission model as outlined in the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html). I'm making the custom form submission model a foreign key in another model (here just called BridgeModel), that will also store additional foreign keys. When the form submits, I'd like the bridge model to automatically update (Create new rows) as well. My biggest challenge is getting access to the current primary key of the submission model so that I can save that to the bridge model. A proof of concept is below

```
class FormBuilderField(AbstractFormField):
    form_builder_page = ParentalKey('FormBuilderPage', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='form_fields')

class FormBuilderPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FormSubmissionsPanel(),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
    ]

    def get_submission_class(self):
        return FormBuilderSubmission

    def process_form_submission(self, form):
        self.get_submission_class().objects.create(form_data=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),page=self)


class FormBuilderSubmission(AbstractFormSubmission):
        def get_data(self):
            form_data = json.loads(self.form_data)

            form_data.update({
                'submit_time': self.submit_time,
             })
            #Tried this, doesn't work. 
            submission_id = FormBuilderSubmission.objects.get(id=self.id)
            update_bridge = BridgeModel.objects.create(form_builder=submission_id)
            process_update = update_bridge.save()

            return form_data

class BridgeModel(models.Model):
    form_builder = models.ForeignKey('FormBuilderSubmission', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other foreign keys here
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working. A bit hacky, using a global variable and overriding the process_form_submission function.

```
class FormBuilderPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
        FormSubmissionsPanel(),
        InlinePanel('form_fields', label="Form fields"),
    ]

def get_submission_class(self):
    return FormBuilderSubmission

def process_form_submission(self, form):
    create_submission = self.get_submission_class().objects.create(form_data=json.dumps(form.cleaned_data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),page=self)

   #grabs the primary key from the submission model row just created
    get_submission = self.get_submission_class().objects.filter(pk=create_submission.id).values('id')
    global get_primary    
    get_primary = [id['id'] for id in get_submission]
```

Now from any model you have access to that primary key to save it as a foreign key

```
    update_bridge = BridgeModel(form_builder_id=get_primary[0])
    update_bridge.save()
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but so far it's meeting my needs.